# Map grouped dictionary of multidimensional array to struct

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a multidimensional array: `tempCalculatorArray [[String]]` - it always carries 2 Strings i.e. "AMT", "Simple scoring system".

I want to display my array in a `UITableView` and have it grouped into sections based the the first letters of the first String value.

Thus far I have created a grouped dictionary from the array based on the first letter of the first string. I have then created a sorted array of the keys used to group the dictionary.

```
let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: tempCalculatorArray, by: { $0[0].prefix(1) } )

let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
```

These appear to work as expected with the values being:

```swift
keys = ["A", "C", "G", "N", "T", "W"] 

groupedDirectory = [
    "G": [
        ["GCS", "Some basic description text"],
    ],
    "N": [
        ["NEWS2", "Some basic description text"],
    ],
    "A": [
        ["AMTS", "Some very basic description text"],
        ["AUDIT-C", "Some really basic description text"],
    ],
    "W": [
        ["WELLS DVT", "Some basic description text"],
        ["WELLS PE", "Some basic description text"],
    ],
    "T": [
        ["TRUELOVE WITTS", "Some basic description text"],
    ],
    "C": [
        ["CURB65", "Some basic description text"],
    ]
]
```

I have created a struct to hold the information I want to then access in the various table functions: letter being the key ie. 'A' 'B' 'C', 'title' being the first string from the grouped array and 'tagline' being the second.

```
struct Section {
   let letter : String
   let title : String
   let tagline : String
}
```

The issue I'm having is I don't understand how to map the above grouped dictionary to the struct with all A's together, all B's together etc. I've created a `var sections = {Section}()` to hold the information.

I've seen examples with only basic array to dictionary, and got this working. However I can't find out how to do this with a multidimensional array to dictionary. I've tried the below, but it is completely wrong and keep getting errors for title and tagline commands:

```
sections = keys.map {
    Section(
        letter: $0,
        title: groupedDictionary[$0]![$0].sorted(),
        tagline: groupedDictionary[$0]![$1].sorted()
    )
}
```

Any help appreciated. Once I've got the 'sections' struct filled I already known how to use this in the `UITableView`.

Comment: You can't with a simple `map()` because for one letter, you can have multiple sections. map transform ONE value into another value., here, it's unclear what should be `section` for letter `"A"` for instance. Do you want two sections then?

Comment: Don't you want instead `struct Section { let letter : String let items : [Item] struct Item { let title : String let tagline : String } }`?

Comment: Then, it'd be `let sections = groupedDirectory.map { aSectionDict in let items = aSectionDict.value.map { aSectionValue in Section.Item(title: aSectionValue[0], tagline: aSectionValue[1]) } return Section(letter: aSectionDict.key, items: items) }.sorted(by: { $0.letter < $1.letter })`. So clarify what you really want first.

Comment: Makes complete sense, thank you. Will get onto it next few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `Section` is wrong. Currently, it can't handle the `"A"` section of your sample.

It'd be better like that:

```
struct Section { 
    let letter: String 
    let items: [Item] 

    struct Item { 
        let title: String 
        let tagline: String
    }
}
```

Now, you can map:

```
let sections = groupedDirectory.map { aSectionDict in 
    let items = aSectionDict.value.map { aSectionValue in
        Section.Item(title: aSectionValue[0], tagline: aSectionValue[1])
    }
    return Section(letter: aSectionDict.key, items: items)
}.sorted(by: { $0.letter < $1.letter })
```

Comment: Perfect. Only update is slight change to code is String(aSectionDict.key) instead of aSectionDoct.key..... sections = groupedDirectory.map { aSectionDict in
            let items = aSectionDict.value.map { aSectionValue in
                Section.Item(title: aSectionValue[0], tagline: aSectionValue[1])
            }
            return Section(letter: String(aSectionDict.key), items: items)
        }.sorted(by: { $0.letter < $1.letter })

Answer (score 0):

@Larme above gave the answer. Very clear. For anyone else finding this useful, the only addition I have is retrieving the variables for use in UITableView

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {return sections.count}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {return sections[section].items.count}


func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {return sections.map{$0.letter}}
    

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {return sections[section].letter}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? tableCell else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
                }
let section = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
            
let title = section.title
let tagline = section.tagline
    
    
// Configure Cell
cell.title.text = String(title)
cell.tagline.text = String(tagline)
return cell
}
```